# passing values from uitableview to uicollectionview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

How can I pass parsed values from a url which has been used in an UITableview to a UICollectionview(scrolled horizontally) which has been used in each of the UITableviews cell? I want do this in swift language.

I am using a model with the name "collectionCat".

```
import Foundation

public class CollectionCat{



    var brandid:String = ""
    var brandname:String = ""
    var result:String = ""
    var noitems:String = ""



}
```

I am also using Alamofire to parse data from url.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.startActivityAnimating(message: "", type: NVActivityIndicatorType.BallClipRotate, color: AppColor.AppRed, padding: 10)
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://goringr.co.in/Mathrubhumi_project_ios/brand.php", parameters: ["": ""])
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                print("Validation Successful")
                self.jsonResultParse(response.result.value!)
                self.stopActivityAnimating()
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
                self.stopActivityAnimating()
                // return userCatagory
            }


    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
  if JSONArray.count != 0 {
        //_ = [UserCatagory]()


        for i:Int in 0 ..< JSONArray.count  {

            let jObject = JSONArray[i] as! NSDictionary

            let uCollect:CollectionCat = CollectionCat()
            uCollect.brandid = (jObject["brandid"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? ""
            uCollect.brandname = (jObject["brandname"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? ""
            uCollect.result = (jObject["result"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? ""
            uCollect.noitems = (jObject["noitems"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? ""

            collect.append(uCollect)
            print("collect COUNT ",collect.count)
        }

        self.newTable.reloadData()

    }



}
```

What i dont know  is how to transfer the stored data to UICollection view which is in each cell of the mentioned UITableview.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // collectMaster = collect[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!  SecondHomeViewCell

   // collectMaster = CollectionCat()
    cell.get = ????

    return cell
}
```

Can anyone Please help me with this?

The SecondHomeViewCell's code goes like this.

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
import Alamofire
import NVActivityIndicatorView



class SecondHomeViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!



    var genre:CollectionCat? = nil{
    didSet {
                collectionView.reloadData()

            }

    }




     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return genre!.brandid

       // return genre
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("secondHome", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SecondHomeCollectionViewCell

             if let genre = genre {
            cell.genre = genre.brandid[indexPath.row]

        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
        let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 5
        let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    }



}
```

Comment: can you include the code from your `SecondHomeViewCell` class

Comment: In your SecondHomeViewCell, add collection view via storyboard @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! , cell.setData(collect[indexPath.row) , And inside setData, set this array as data model of collection view

Answer (score 0):

Add a array in your ViewController, call it

```
var collCat = [CollectionCat]()


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let collectMaster = collCat[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!  SecondHomeViewCell


    cell.brandID = collectMaster.brandid
    //and so on

    return cell
}
```

If this is not the answer you are looking for, please tell me. Because I wanted to clarify but I don't have the ability to comment yet. I need to reach 50 reputation to be able to comment and ask some clarifications.

Comment: Just now I have added the code for the secondHomeViewCell. Can you please look into that too and also give me an answer including that.

Comment: can you please also tell me how to call it in the SecondHomeViewCell

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to collection view by creating function in UITableviewCell custom class

```
class SecondHomeViewCell: UITableViewCell{
//Array containing modals for particular tableview cell index path  


 var arrDataFromViewController = NSArray()
    func getData(arrData:NSArray){
        arrDataFromViewController = arrData
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.reloadData()
        }


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!



    var genre:CollectionCat? = nil{
    didSet {
                collectionView.reloadData()

            }

    }




     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return genre!.brandid

       // return genre
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("secondHome", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SecondHomeCollectionViewCell

             if let genre = genre {
            cell.genre = genre.brandid[indexPath.row]

        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
        let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 5
        let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    }



}
```

//Now in tableview data source method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // collectMaster = collect[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!  SecondHomeViewCell

   // collectMaster = CollectionCat()
    cell.getData =  yourArray[indexPath.row]//Get Array data

    return cell
}
```